# How to migrate a Django app with postgres database

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have just inherrited a jDango app with .tar.gz compression extention and a .sql file which is a postgreSQL database dump. My mission which I did not choose to accept is to somehow find its way onto AWS. I'm not familier with Django. I believe the app was built with the Ubuntu OS.

I thought that maybe the best thing would be to get postgreSQL and Django working on my local machine. I have all working in vanilla on Windows, and Ubuntu (virtual box) and have set up Amazon Lightsail with a postgreSQL database..

I'm a bit stuck as to what to do next to migrate the app. Would it all be CLI/Cmd Prompt/Terminal or is there a procedure I should be using.

I'm guessing it's not as simple as importing the database and then copying files over and replacing existing vanilla Django ones? Any pointers would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: Please read the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/

Answer (score 0):

Open your editor terminal and write code below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```